# Screeching Noise

Tags: nissan

Last month I had front brakes and rotors put on. Today, while driving downhill and making a turn, this loud screeching noise started. I was also applying brakes when this happened. I parked my car on the hill, facing up. When I got back in, I started it, began to drive. Still had screeching noise. Drove about a mile and it stopped. Everything else seemed fine.

Comment: Typical of a loose power steering belt.

Answer (score 1):

Double check that everything was installed correctly if you are the one who installed them. If you didnt, take it back to the shop that replaced them and explain whats going on, if they dont help you then find a new tire shop.

Did you get standard OE parts, whats the year make an model?

Comment: I took it to a shop. It’s 2016 Nissan Rogue